# Why pygame.event.get() returns EventList?

Tags: python, pygame

Pygame.event is a queue. Usually, when I want to extract element from queue I expect it to return the element on the top, which is the first element, that entered the queue. Even Python's `queue.get()` works this way. So I'm wondering why `pygame.event.get()` returns list of all unprocessed events instead of returning the first event it got.

Comment: Sounds like a question for the pygame author?

Comment: Because it's a quick way of emptying the entire queue to free up the buffer. If you don't want to use any of it, it's a quick way to "clear and continue". If you actually were forced to pop every item, that would slow down rendering time. Just my penny on the dime, not the author of Pygame, but I've spent enough time around otpmizing stuff that I can see an optimization a mile away.

Answer (score 2):

Pygame has several options. Either use [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) to get a list of all pending events or use [`pygame.event.poll()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.poll) to get a single event from the queue. The returned events are removed from the queue.
It is even possible to wait for a single event by [`pygame.event.wait()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.wait).

Comment: I would also guess that the `get` method lets you process all events since last time you accessed the events, using you own priorities, instead of having the engine be the only mechanism to decide priorities. I would call that good design decision.

Comment: I understood your answer well, and even voted it up. I just mentioned that providing the functionality that `get` does makes a lot of sense, if you want to process the events according to your own priorities, rather than rely on the order induced by, for example, `poll`.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron *"I just mentioned that providing the functionality that get does makes a lot of sense, if you want to process the events according to your own priorities"* - !? You can't change the order of the events. Either you get all the events by a list or you get them one by one. But the order depends on the order in the queue. Each event you get/wait/poll is removed from the queue.